# ASP.NET Web API help pages in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to use ASP.NET Web API help pages (i.e. not web api itself, but the area and help pages) in Visual Studio 2010? Latest version at time of writing requires Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 5.0.0), which requires Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.0.0), which requires Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.0.0), which requires .NET 4.5.

Is there a workaround or some way to manually add help pages?

Source: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/

Comment: +1 to the series of "which requires". Made me laugh because I found myself in that situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the latest Web API packages (Web API 2, a.k.a. 5.0.0) require .NET 4.5.

But there is nothing stopping you from installing the older version - the last stable .NET 4 package is this http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/4.0.30506

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage -Version 4.0.30506`

It works with `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 4.0.20710.0)`

Comment: Worked like a charm on first go, and allowed me to use the Package Manager Console instead for once instead of the package management GUI. I should have checked for previous stable versions - I've learned my lesson. Thanks Filip!

Comment: Thanks for this too. I wish nuget would notify you about previous versions that are compatible with what you have.